# Live webcam publishing using jw Player

Tags: javascript, flash, jwplayer

I use JW player just to publish my live webcam. Live webcam stream. I use the following code where the webcam is.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var flashvars =
  {
    'streamer':                     'rtmp://69.160.44.133/SOSample',
    'file':                         'samplefile',
    'type':                         'camera',
    'controlbar':                   'bottom',
    'stretching':                   'none',
    'frontcolor':                   '86C29D',  // text & icons                  (green)
    'backcolor':                    '849BC1',  // playlist background           (blue)
    'lightcolor':                   'C286BA',  // selected text/track highlight (pink)
    'screencolor':                  'FFFFFF',  // screen background             (black)
    'id':                           'playerID',
    'autostart':                    'true'
  };

  var params =
  {
    'allowfullscreen':              'true',
    'allowscriptaccess':            'always',
    'bgcolor':                      '#FFFFFF'
  };

  var attributes =
  {
    'id':                           'playerID',
    'name':                         'playerID'
  };
  swfobject.embedSWF('player.swf', 'player', '320', '260', '9.0.124', false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

And the following code where the stream will be displayed.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jwplayer.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
'type': 'rtmp',
'streamer': 'rtmp://69.160.44.133/SOSample',
'autostart': 'true',
'bufferlength': '3',
'file': '<?php echo $selid; ?>',
'controlbar': 'bottom',
'width': '320',
'height': '260'
});
</script>
```

Everything is going ok, but audio is not coming. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a link to where this is being run?

Comment: The link below is for recording
[link](http://69.160.44.133/~lookeast/show_cam.php?selid=testcam)[/link]
and the link below is for display
[link](http://69.160.44.133/~lookeast/show_live.php?selid=testcam)[/link]

Comment: Are you using Red5? I'm afraid the camera type was a feature of the old 4.4 JW Player which was subsequently removed in future versions because it did not work properly.